# Xcode skip auto-paired character

Tags: xcode

Xcode auto-generates closing quotations, but I still have to type the quotation or press the right arrow key to get past the characters. I was wondering if there were a way to replicate the behavior of Textmate, where if you command-enter, you automatically skip the auto-generated closing quotations and start a new line.

You can see the textmate behavior described here (4.1):
https://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text